# How can you let two JVM's communicate without RMI or Sockets?

Tags: java, jvm

Is it possible to let two separate JVM's communicate with each other without RMI or a Socket?

My situation is as following:

I have a server (java app) in one console, in a command line interface. I can log in to the computer with SSH, so I have got another terminal. I want now to start a little java program, which can communicate with the server. This is to control the server, so there isn't a lot of traffic (just some small strings passing around).

I'd like not to use a Socket or RMI, as it uses another port number.

Is a PipedWriter an option? But how will the other JVM now where to find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a `PipedWriter`; that's only for communication between threads in the same process. You also can't use an unnamed OS pipe, as there's no relationship between the processes. You *could* use an OS fifo (assuming you're on Unix, when you'd make it with the system `mkfifo` command; I don't know the equivalent API for Windows well enough to help there) but I've no idea how good Java will be at handling such named pipes.

The simplest mechanisms are to use a watched file or a server socket that is only bound to a port on localhost, 127.0.0.1. (By binding it in such a way, it becomes *impossible* to access the socket from off the machine without some kind of local program. Or a suitably-configured SSH tunnel.) The advantage *and* disadvantage of the watched-file method is that it needs somewhere that both processes can see (and presumably write to). An administration socket is somewhat more exposed, but handles two-way comms much more easily; if that matters to you, do consider it as Java's got good (if a little low-level for my tastes) support for sockets.

If you're thinking about a shared file solution, consider whether to make that file a database; there's a JDBC driver for SQLite and that supports safe concurrent access (and guards against problems with concurrent writes I bet you've never thought of). It also might mean you can avoid having to write a special client; there's a wealth of existing tools.

Comment: Big thanks! I want to construct an elegant, nice solution, and I hoped there was a cleaner solution then a Socket, but it seems there is none :( . Well, I'll go for the Socket, as the watched file is even uglier (sorry for saying that). A fifo could be a solution, but would break portability, and is ugly too.

Comment: IPC *is* ugly (or is a wrapper round ugly) because at some point you've got to serialize messages between processes and notify the other end that a message is there. (Or you use shared memory and techniques based on that, but that is _even trickier to get right_.)

Comment: Yes, that's a fact... However, I can't see an easy and clean workaround for this specific situation, so I'll go with the cleanest solution.

Comment: Another solution, similar to Unix FIFO, would be to use a Unix socket: http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/